# Get product variation's SKU

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to e-mail different information to my customers depending on SKU of a products they purchased. The problem is that my products have variations, and each variation has it's own SKU.

I know how to loop through client's order items and get a products SKU ...

```
// Loop through order items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
  // Get product ID
  $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); 

  // Get an instance of Product object
  $item->get_product(); 

  // Get SKU
  $sku = $product->get_sku();

  echo $sku;
}
```

But this code shows SKU of the "original" product, not it's variation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that was all about my inattentiveness... The code worked fine but the test product's variation had no individual SKU, that's why always got the parent's SKU.